# Prevent bots from accessing rails active_storage images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, robots.txt, rails-activestorage

My site has a large number of graphs which are recalculated each day as new data is available. The graphs are stored on Amazon S3 using `active_storage`. A typical example would be

```
# app/models/graph.rb
class Graph < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :plot
end
```

and in the view

```
<%= image_tag graphs.latest.plot %>
```

where `graphs.latest` retrieves the latest graph.  Each day, a new graph and attached plot is created and the old graph/plot is deleted.

A number of bots, including from Google and Yandex are indexing the graphs, but then are generating exceptions when the bot returns and accesses the image again at urls like

```
www.myapp.com/rails/active_storage/representations/somelonghash
```

Is there a way to produce a durable link for the plot that does not expire when the graph/plot is deleted and then recalculated.   Failing this, is there a way to block bots from accessing these plots.

Note that I currently have a catchall at the end of the `routes.rb` file:

```
get '*all', to: 'application#route_not_found', constraints: lambda { |req|
      req.path.exclude? 'rails/active_storage'
    } if Rails.env.production?
```

The exclusion of active storage in the catchall is in response to this [issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/31228). It is tempting to remove the active_storage exemption, but this might then stop proper active_storage routes.

Maybe I can put something in `rack_rewrite.rb` to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting question.

A simple solution would be to use the `send_data` functionality to send the image directly. However, that can have it's own issues, mostly in terms of probably increasing server bandwidth usage (and reducing server performance). However, a solution like that is what you need if you don't want to go through the trouble of the below as far as creating a redirect model goes and the logic around that.

---

Original Answer

The redirect will require setting up some sort of `Redirects::Graph` model. That basically can verify that a graph was deleted and redirect to the new graph instead of the requested one. It would have two fields, a `old_signed_id` (`biglonghash`) and a `new_signed_id`.

Every time you delete

We'll need to populate the redirects model and also add a new entry every time a new graph is created (we should be able to generate the `signed_id` from the blob somehow).

For performance, and to avoid tons of redirects in a row which may result in a different error/issue. You'll have to manage the request change. IE: Say you now have a redirect `A => B`, you delete `B` replacing it with `C` now you need a `A => C` and `B => C` (to avoid an `A => B => C` redirect), this chain could get rather long indeed. This can be handled efficiently by just adding the new `signed_id => new_id` index and doing a `Redirects::Graph.where(new_signed_id: old_signed_id).update_all(new_signed_id: new_signed_id)` to update all the relevant old redirects, whenever you re-generate the graph.

The controller itself is trickier, cleanest method I can think of is to monkey patch the `ActiveStorage::RepresentationsController` to add a `before_action` that does something like this (may not work as-is, the params[:signed_id] and the representations path may not be right):

```
before_action :redirect_if_needed

def redirect_if_needed
  redirect_model = Redirects::Graph.find_by(old_signed_id: params[:signed_id])
  redirect_to rails_activestorage_representations_path(
    signed_id: redirect_model.new_signed_id
  ) if redirect_model.present?
end
```

If you have version control setup for your database (IE: Papertrail gem or something) you may be able to work out the `old_signed_id` and `new_signed_id` with a bit of work and build the redirects for the urls currently causing errors. Otherwise, sadly this approach will only prevent future errors, and it may be impossible to get the current broken urls working.

Ideally, though you would update the blob itself to use the new graph instead of the old graph rather than deleting, but not sure that's possible/practical.

Comment: Thank  you for this. Although it is much more complex than I hoped, this appears to have potential, but I do not have any idea how to 'generate the signed_id from the blob somehow'.  Also, wouldn't the redirect entries need to be stored in the database?

Comment: https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.3.1/classes/ActiveStorage/Blob.html Looks like it's just `signed_id` on the blob, so don't actually generate it. As for the redirects, yes, you'd have to store them in the database, only way to avoid that is to a) not delete them in the first place, and instead update the blob to avoid the signed_id from being invalidated, or b) prevent robots from grabbing the ID. This might be possible if you can use your own URL to serve the image instead of active records. I believe you can use `send_data` to send the image instead of using the asset pipeline.

Comment: If I use ```send_data``` would the url remain constant?  If so, it sounds an excellent solution.  What would be the syntax assuming the image is ```graph.latest.plot```?  Are there any drawbacks, e.g. does it stream from active storage rather than through the server?

Comment: URL should remain the same something like `/download/graphs/vpq34or8vawo`, the last bit being the ID of the graph (friendly id gem helpful here, or something like it). It would stream through the server I would imagine, so that could be a server bandwidth usage issue. As to how, search online for "rails send_data images" for examples of usage. In this case, you would just need to ensure you have a overarching model that is tracking the graphs, so it knows the correct image to send.

Comment: In regards to the streaming through the server, do you think the active_storage js library would support direct uploads with ```direct_upload: true```?  It looks to me that the ```send_data``` approach provides a viable solution, so I think you have earned the bonus, thank you. However, I am hesitant to accept the current answer as it requires reading a large amount of text. I think others would find it confusing. How about you either edit it, or provide a second succinct answer in regard to the ```send_data``` approach.

Comment: Um you wouldn't use send_data for anything related to `direct_upload`. This is a download issue not an upload one. I'll edit it to include the send_data bit. Though that may complicate things as you may have to download the image to the server then send it off. Though there may be ways to avoid this. I'd probably try implementing it then accept it works for you. Or you can award the bounty in terms of "helping in going in the right direction" and we can edit the answer with something closer to your final solution.

Comment: It is a while before I can get around to this, so will award you the bonus and accept the answer. It would be good if you could tidy up the answer.  If you do that, maybe we can tidy/delete the comments?

Answer (score 1):

have you tried?

In the [file `/robots.txt` put](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/robots/create-robots-txt):

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /rails/active_storage*
```

Comment: Yes, and it does not work for PetalBot, and possibly other bots.

Comment: @Obromios try 
[like this](https://www.cleverbridge.com/robots.txt)

you can just specify ->


User-agent: PetalBot
Disallow: /

Comment: I did try that, but PetalBot appears to ignore robots.txt